# Changing Docker-compose.yml for port binding not updating correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, webserver, airflow, port

I have an Airflow webserver running on a remote server using Docker compose.
The web server is listening on port 8080 but when I checked listening port, it is binding on tcp6. I need it on tcp4 so I specified port as follow in docker-compose.yml: 0.0.0.0:8053:8080.
This is still not appearing in tcp4. Is there something I can do please? I have been stuck on that for too long now.

netstat:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9990            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9869636    25641/python3       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9991            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          35554015   8522/python3        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29131         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          41896      4891/mdsd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          148941     27909/rpcbind       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          22865      1099/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15857      1097/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::9990                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          9869637    25641/python3       
tcp6       0      0 :::9991                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          35554016   8522/python3        
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          148944     27909/rpcbind       
tcp6       0      0 :::8053                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          62406994   16601/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          22867      1099/dnsmasq        
tcp6       0      0 :::1270                 :::*                    LISTEN      10002      15888      1182/omiengine      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          15859      1097/sshd
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2.2'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    PATH: /home/airflow/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/20210511_DATADOWN_RETRY:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./downloads:/opt/airflow/downloads
    - ./script:/opt/airflow/script
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:8053:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 100s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 100s
      timeout: 100s
      retries: 100
    restart: always


  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
     _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  chrome:
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
      hostname: chrome
      privileged: true
      shm_size: 2g
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./downloads:/tmp
  framework:
      build: .
      depends_on:
          - chrome

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.2
USER root

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        vim \
        apt-utils \
        build-essential \
        wget \
        curl \
        sqlite3 \
        libsqlite3-dev \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y \
 && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 mssql-tools unixodbc-dev

#RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

RUN adduser airflow sudo
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

USER airflow

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user streamlit xlutils xlrd Unidecode openpyxl apache-airflow-providers-papermill jupyter bs4 retry requests more_itertools selenium chromedriver-binary vaex tqdm cleanco pyodbc

RUN pip install -U jupyter

RUN   echo $"import nest_asyncio \n\
            nest_asyncio.apply()" >> /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/papermill/operators/papermill.py


RUN mkdir /opt/airflow/dl_from_volume

## StreamLit app ##
EXPOSE 8501
CMD streamlit run /opt/airflow/script/PTS_Tools/STREAMLIT_APP/app.py
```

iptables output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.21.0.4           tcp dpt:webcache

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  Output of `netstat` aside, can you make a normal IPv4 connection to the published port?

Comment: @DavidMaze I can make a normal IPv4 connection using port 9990 and 9991. But I cannot use 8053 that I use in the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: As David mentioned, please post your `docker-compose.yaml` file with your question.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram Sorry for omitting it. Please look at the edit

Comment: @DavidMaze I have added Docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile